# Clean way to run Perl CGI script on Mac?

Tags: perl, cgi

I'm trying to run a server to serve a Perl file on my Mac, but I'd like to not use Apache and its CGI. Is there a clean way, a la Python's SimpleHTTPServer, to run Perl without mucking with Apache?